# ng-draggbale directive Angular not dragging properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, draggable

I'm having a problem with [ng-draggable](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable) directive .
The problem is that i can drag data only when i add this in my table :

**Markup**

```
 <span class="title">Drop area #2</span>
```

[**Plunker With Problem**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yaqKQHXd3NTsXIeMDUrQ?p=preview)

Any idea would appreciated.

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: you don't have any `onDragSuccess` function in your first list in the Plunker, and the second one which does have an `onDragSuccess` isn't populating with any data to drag.  Your Plunker doesn't seem to be useful to helping solve your issue.

Comment: this plunk works very well . so you think , this is because of onDragSuccess ?